# Efficient ROC/AUC calculation & time complexity

Tags: machine-learning, roc, auc

Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC) and Area Under Curve (AUC) are very known concepts. I have used them repeatedly (using libraries like scikit-learn), but never actually learned how to implement them.

The obvious implementation that comes to mind is to: fix a step, delta, divide the interval 0 - 1 with delta, and for all those thresholds, compute the TPR and FPR.

From https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/classification/roc-and-auc, I learned that "To compute the points in a ROC curve, we could evaluate a logistic regression model many times with different classification thresholds, but this would be inefficient. Fortunately, there's an efficient, sorting-based algorithm that can provide this information for us, called AUC." - this got me thinking, what algorithms are used for efficient ROC/AUC calculation for a really large number of samples? What is the time complexity for such an efficient algorithm?

Comment: I don't know where this idea to "fix a step, delta" comes from. A ROC curve assesses all thresholds (from -Inf to +Info, not 0-1), which you can simplify to the values seen in the data. Not fixed intervals. Your answer makes it pretty clear, but I've seen this error very often recently.

Comment: I may be wrong, but that probably comes from the fact that, most models predict probability (instead of scores which can take up any value). So, it's common to explore thresholds in the range 0 - 1 (inclusive).

Answer (score 2):

So, I looked into the implementation of `scikit-learn`. I will try to explain the algorithm here.

Let's consider the official example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn import metrics
>>> y = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2])
>>> scores = np.array([0.1, 0.4, 0.35, 0.8])
>>> fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y, scores, pos_label=2)
>>> fpr
array([0. , 0. , 0.5, 0.5, 1. ])
>>> tpr
array([0. , 0.5, 0.5, 1. , 1. ])
>>> thresholds
array([1.8 , 0.8 , 0.4 , 0.35, 0.1 ])
```

**Step 1:** The first thing to decide is how many threshold points do we need?

- We don't need more than the number of samples for probability/score. Let's consider this case. We have  `scores = [0.1, 0.4, 0.35, 0.8]`, if we choose a point between 0.35 and 0.4, it will not add any new point on the ROC curve (same as 0.4). We can further reduce the number of thresholds by selecting only the unique thresholds (set). We can also remove any collinear points.

Complexity: `O(n)`

**Step 2:** How to calculate TPR, and FPR?

We can, of course, calculate TPR and FPR, by considering each threshold and counting how many scores are above that point, and checking their true labels.

Now, this will be `O(N^2)`.

But we can use a greedy approach to make it much more efficient. What happens if we sort the scores array?

```
y_score = [0.8, 0.4, 0.35, 0.1]

y_true = [1, 0, 1, 0] # converted to binary
```

Now, if we iterate `y_score`, for `0.8`, if we have `y_true = 1` then, the true positive count would be 1, because there is only 1 true label which is `>= 0.8`. If we move to 0.4, we know `0.8 and 0.4 >= 0.4` but for 0.4 the label is false, so still, the true positive count is 1, at 0.35, we have 0.35 and 0.4 and 0.8 >= 0.35, and there are 2 true labels, that means, the true positive count is 2.
Now, we can easily calculate this with a cumulative sum.

```
TPC = [1, 1, 2, 2]
```

We can normalize this by the last element `TPC[-1]` to get TPR.

```
TPR = [0.5, 0.5, 1, 1]
```

This is the same as the output from scikit-learn. The extra `1 + max(score)` threshold is there to make sure the ROC starts at (0, 0).

Same way, we can calculate the false positive count with `1 + index - true positive count`.

So, total time complexity: `O(N*logN)` (for sorting)